# SharePoint 2019 - Document Sets are deleted from the list by SharePoint and re-created

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list template that has on it some content types and document sets. When I create a list from that list template something strange happens. After the creation of the new list is ready, trash is full of document sets. The list is created as expected, with content types and document sets, but the trash also contains document sets. Anyone know`s` why ?

Comment: Please explain what trash is referring to. When you create a list based on list template, the newly created list will contain all the content in the list template.

Comment: By trash I'm refering to site collection trash. In trash/recycle bin you can find everything that was deleted from the site. So I am creating a list from a list template that has applied on it document sets. After the new list is created, recycle bin contains the document sets. The list is created fine, as expected and contains the document sets, but I don't know why document sets that are applied to list are also added to recycle bin